# UpdateContactFlowContent(): When I am trying to update the content, getting "InvalidRequestException"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

`UpdateContactFlowContent()`

When I am trying to update the content, I am getting `InvalidRequestException` though I have done ARN mapping correctly. Replaced `SourceARN` with `TargetARN`. But still getting the error.

I have formatted the JSON to make it more readable. Whereas in actual I am using the exact JSON as it is output from `DescribeContactFlow()` in another instance.

I am unable to understand why I am getting this error and if I can check logs to find out exact error position.

> "Version":"2019-10-30","StartAction":"4084e7ed-6467-4748-bf0a-c93955f06726","Metadata":{"entryPointPosition":{"x":14.4,"y":14.4},"ActionMetadata":{"fffa1a93-4c23-4ed2-a075-d2ff8382d33b":{"position":{"x":396.8,"y":686.4000000000001}},"4084e7ed-6467-4748-bf0a-c93955f06726":{"position":{"x":54.400000000000006,"y":312.8},"dynamicMetadata":{}},"29445da8-c159-4ed3-a32f-17e61086158d":{"position":{"x":720.8000000000001,"y":544.8000000000001}},"0116f219-faa4-4f40-926b-ae1b9eafbe8a":{"position":{"x":390.40000000000003,"y":181.60000000000002},"parameters":{"Attributes":{"isHoliday":{"useDynamic":true}}},"dynamicParams":["isHoliday"]},"2f869572-de59-477d-aaff-527c9569b530":{"position":{"x":1302.4,"y":520.8000000000001}},"1c946c7b-83b6-48af-8173-6cd4864462bf":{"position":{"x":1673.6000000000001,"y":530.4}},"8b84a239-3ab2-43fd-89f1-1ec0c5e31ee3":{"position":{"x":714.4000000000001,"y":76},"conditionMetadata":[{"id":"19b6f9cf-89c4-43d5-a1e9-22c21065eae2","operator":{"name":"Equals","value":"Equals","shortDisplay":"="},"value":"true"}]},"c6d7c6ca-b260-451a-a5a3-82c73da1e3a3":{"position":{"x":1269.6000000000001,"y":58.400000000000006}},"2afe0399-5abb-46a2-a55c-1bf09c88f72d":{"position":{"x":988,"y":-140.8},"parameters":{"ContactFlowId":{"displayName":"Rolando Test 3"}},"ContactFlow":{"text":"Rolando Test 3"}}}},"Actions":[{"Parameters":{"Text":"Error"},"Identifier":"fffa1a93-4c23-4ed2-a075-d2ff8382d33b","Type":"MessageParticipant","Transitions":{"NextAction":"1c946c7b-83b6-48af-8173-6cd4864462bf"}},{"Parameters":{"LambdaFunctionARN":"arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:180398087396:function:holidaySchedule","InvocationTimeLimitSeconds":"3"},"Identifier":"4084e7ed-6467-4748-bf0a-c93955f06726","Type":"InvokeLambdaFunction","Transitions":{"NextAction":"0116f219-faa4-4f40-926b-ae1b9eafbe8a","Errors":[{"NextAction":"fffa1a93-4c23-4ed2-a075-d2ff8382d33b","ErrorType":"NoMatchingError"}]}},{"Parameters":{"Text":"Error 2"},"Identifier":"29445da8-c159-4ed3-a32f-17e61086158d","Type":"MessageParticipant","Transitions":{"NextAction":"8b84a239-3ab2-43fd-89f1-1ec0c5e31ee3"}},{"Parameters":{"Attributes":{"isHoliday":"$.External.isHoliday"}},"Identifier":"0116f219-faa4-4f40-926b-ae1b9eafbe8a","Type":"UpdateContactAttributes","Transitions":{"NextAction":"8b84a239-3ab2-43fd-89f1-1ec0c5e31ee3","Errors":[{"NextAction":"29445da8-c159-4ed3-a32f-17e61086158d","ErrorType":"NoMatchingError"}]}},{"Parameters":{"Text":"Its not a holiday. Get to work!!"},"Identifier":"2f869572-de59-477d-aaff-527c9569b530","Type":"MessageParticipant","Transitions":{"NextAction":"1c946c7b-83b6-48af-8173-6cd4864462bf"}},{"Parameters":{},"Identifier":"1c946c7b-83b6-48af-8173-6cd4864462bf","Type":"DisconnectParticipant","Transitions":{}},{"Parameters":{"ComparisonValue":"$.Attributes.isHoliday"},"Identifier":"8b84a239-3ab2-43fd-89f1-1ec0c5e31ee3","Type":"Compare","Transitions":{"NextAction":"2f869572-de59-477d-aaff-527c9569b530","Conditions":[{"NextAction":"2afe0399-5abb-46a2-a55c-1bf09c88f72d","Condition":{"Operator":"Equals","Operands":["true"]}}],"Errors":[{"NextAction":"2f869572-de59-477d-aaff-527c9569b530","ErrorType":"NoMatchingCondition"}]}},{"Parameters":{"Text":"Its a Holiday!!!!!"},"Identifier":"c6d7c6ca-b260-451a-a5a3-82c73da1e3a3","Type":"MessageParticipant","Transitions":{"NextAction":"1c946c7b-83b6-48af-8173-6cd4864462bf"}},{"Parameters":{"ContactFlowId":"arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:180398087396:instance/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/contact-flow/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},"Identifier":"2afe0399-5abb-46a2-a55c-1bf09c88f72d","Type":"TransferToFlow","Transitions":{"NextAction":"c6d7c6ca-b260-451a-a5a3-82c73da1e3a3","Errors":[{"NextAction":"c6d7c6ca-b260-451a-a5a3-82c73da1e3a3","ErrorType":"NoMatchingError"}]}}]

Comment: Can you show us your code? Is there really nothing before `"Version"` (such as an opening bracket)? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for taking interest and guiding me on how to ask a good question ! However I am now able to update the Contact Flow successfully as I was missing opening and closing braces before updating the contact flow. I think we can close the issue now.

Comment: Great to hear that you've fixed it! Feel free to add an Answer to help future readers. Or, if you don't think that your question will help other people, feel free to delete it.

Comment: I was only missing curly braces{} in the beginning and end. Adding curly braces and i was able to update contact flow successfully.